NextJS 14 and Firebase Messaging PWA Push notification says: This browser doesn't support the API's required to use the Firebase SDK
I'm building a progressive web app with NextJs 14, Firebase Messaging, and trying to implement web push notifications with service workers.
But each time I run the app it says: FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the APIs required to use the Firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser).
My codes are here:
firebase-config.js
`// firebase-config.js

// other configs......

export const messaging = getMessaging(app);

export const generateToken = async () => {
  const permission = await Notification.requestPermission();

  if(permission === 'granted') {
    const newSw = await navigator.serviceWorker.register(
      '/firebase-messaging-sw.js'
    );

    const token = await getToken(messaging, {
      vapidKey: 'BHi5Ru9dSFG9XAkwuYDj5Y49_8F9OgUdwI81tUz5oNfjoG_c_txuqm3HyK4aTZeG4ne92bn-n2On_ZRQNfbd7ds',
      serviceWorkerRegistration: newSw
    });

    console.log(token);
  }
}

getToken(messaging, { vapidKey: '<YOUR_PUBLIC_VAPID_KEY_HERE>' }).then(async (currentToken) => {
  if (currentToken) {
    // Send the token to your server and update the UI if necessary
    // ...
  } else {
    // Show permission request UI
    console.log('No registration token available. Request permission to generate one.');
    const permission = await Notification.requestPermission();
  }
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log('An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
  // ...
});`

firebase-messaging-sw.js
// firebase-messaging-sw.js

importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-messaging.js');

firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: '******',
  authDomain: '******',
  projectId: '******',
  storageBucket: '******',
  messagingSenderId: '******',
  appId: '******',
  measurementId: '******'
});

const messaging = firebase.messaging();

// Background notifications will be received here
messaging.onBackgroundMessage(payload => {
  self.registration.showNotification(payload.notification.title, { body: payload.notification.body })
});

self.addEventListener('message', e => {
  // Handle incoming messages from the main appliation
  const { type, data } = e.data;

  if(type === 'showNotification') {
    self.registration.showNotification(data.title, {
      body: data.body,
      icon: 'https://i.postimg.cc/ZnfQpG5L/redsouls-logo.webp'
    });
    
    // Add toast notification
    self.registration.showNotification(data.title);
  }
});

providers.tsx (It's a parent wrapper of the whole app where I implemented theme toggling functionality and added the firebase onmessage listener here)
  // Push notification
  const [FCMToken, setFCMToken] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);

  const getToken = async () => {
    try {
      const token = await firebaseCloudMessaging.init();
      console.log('absdf', token)

      if(token) {
        await firebaseCloudMessaging.getMessage();
        setFCMToken(token);
      }
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {console.log(FCMToken)}, [FCMToken]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker
        .register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js')
        .then(registration => {
        console.log('Service worker registered successfully: ' + registration);
        })
        .catch(error => {
        console.log('Service worker registration failed: ' + error);
        });

      navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', event => {
        console.log(event.data.notification)
      })
    }

    async function setToken () {
      await getToken();
    }

    setToken();
  }, []);

The error I'm getting:
Error Image 1
Error Image 2
Please tell me how can I solve this problem I've tried a lot of other methods but it doesn't work.
I was expecting it will work properly and receive push notification even when the pwa is closed.
